When is a family of distributions "closed" with respect to minimal sufficient statistics?
As in the title, I am interested in understanding how to express the idea that a parametric family of distribution is "closed" with respect to minimal sufficient statistics. Before giving the relevant definitions, here is a motivating example of what I have in mind

Example. Consider a random variable $X$ which is known to be normally distributed with given variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\Phi=(\mathcal{N}(\theta,\sigma^2))_{\theta\in\Theta}$ for some $\Theta\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be the family of distributions considered for $X$. Imagine that one observes a sequence of i.i.d. samples from $X$. In this case, a minimal sufficient statistic for $\Phi$ is the sample average, $\overline{X}$. The sample average can take any value in $\mathbb{R}$ hence, if $\Theta\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$, there is a natural sense in which $\Phi$ is not closed with respect to minimal sufficient statistics. Indeed, it is possible that no distribution in $\Phi$ "matches" the statistic. Instead, if $\Theta=\mathbb{R}$ this problem does not arise.

Question How to formalize this situation, in general?
Here is my attempt, which has gaps that need to be filled. I would be more than happy if there was a better formalization than this self-made one.
====================================================================
Let $\mathcal{Y}=\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{N}}Y^t$ be the sample space associated to an outcome space $Y$. Consider a family of probability distributions $\Phi\subseteq\Delta(Y)$ for which there is a measure $\lambda\in\Delta(Y)$ such that each $\varphi\in\Phi$ admits a density $f_{\varphi}$ with respect to $\lambda$. Extend any density $f_{\varphi}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$, defining $\overline{f}_{\varphi}$ mapping
\begin{align*}
    y\equiv (y_1,\dots,y_t)\in Y^t\subseteq\mathcal{Y}\mapsto \prod_{i=1}^{t} f_{\varphi}(y_i)
\end{align*}

A sufficient statistic for $\Phi$ is a function $T_\Phi:\mathcal{Y}\to\mathbb{R}^N$ such that there exist $h:\mathcal{Y}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ and $g:\Phi\times \mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}_+$ such that, for each $p_a\in\Theta(a)$ and each $y\in\mathcal{Y}$
\begin{align*}
    \overline{f}_{\phi}(y)=h(y)g(\phi,T_\Phi(y))
\end{align*}
We call $N$ the dimension of the statistic. A sufficient statistic is minimal if
\begin{align*}
    \forall y,y'\in\mathcal{Y}\quad\frac{\overline{f}_{\varphi}(y)}{\overline{f}_{\varphi}(y')}\quad\text{constant in } \varphi\Leftrightarrow T_\Phi(y)=T_\Phi(y')
\end{align*}

Observe that sufficient statistics always exist, as witnessed by the likelihood function. Minimal sufficient statistics might not exist. Let us assume we are in a case when they do (for intance $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and all distributions in $\Phi$ are continuous or all are discrete.
Now, in the Example, the minimal sufficient statistic defines a functional (the first moment) which can be applied to any distribution in $\Phi$. In general, we should seek a definition along the following lines.

Given a minimal sufficient statistic $T_\Phi:\mathcal{Y}\to\mathbb{R}^N$  a sufficient statistic functional is a mapping $\mathcal{T}_\Phi:\Delta(Y)\to\mathbb{R}^N$ which "extends" it, in the sense that
$$\forall y\in\mathcal{Y}\quad \mathcal{T}_\Phi(\eta_y)=T_\Phi(y)$$
where $\eta_y$ is the empirical distribution of the vector $y$.

The first thing I would like to understand is: is it indeed possible to associate a functional with a (minimal) sufficient statistic?
Assuming this is the case, then we could make the following definition

A family of probability distributions $\Phi$ is closed wrt minimal sufficient statistics if, for all minimal sufficient statistics $T_\Phi$,
$$\mathbf{Im}(T_\Phi)\subseteq \mathcal{T}_\Phi(\Phi)$$


The usual definition says a sufficient statistic for $\Phi$ is a function $T:\mathcal Y\to\mathbb R^n$ for which the conditional distribution of $y$ given $T(y)$ does not depend on $\theta.$ The factorization criterion that you state is normally taken to be a consequence of the definition, rather than being considered to be the definition.

What is $\Delta(Y)$?

I'm guessing (but it's only a guess) that what you mean by "complete" is that it is not a subset of a larger family of distributions for which the same statistic is sufficient.

$\Delta(Y)$ denotes the set of probability measures on $Y$. Can you point me to where I use the word complete? More in general  I perceive a lot of unmotivated frustration in your comments. Please elaborate on why you find the question unclear, and I will provide clarification. What is the point of ranting like this?

Typo: Where I wrote "complete" in comments I meant "closed".

I don't know what I wrote that you could consider "ranting". I asked what you mean by $\Delta(Y).$

@MichaelHardy yes, now that you edited your comment this is what you are asking, well done.

There is a simpler way to show that a sufficient statistic always exists: The sample as a whole, i.e. the $t$-tuple of independent observations, is sufficient.
